# How to lock multiple stages of declarative Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run multiple stages inside a lock within a declarative Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        lock(resource: 'myResource') {
            stage('Stage 1') {
                steps {
                  echo "my first step"
                }
            }

            stage('Stage 2') {
                steps {
                  echo "my second step"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Started by user anonymous
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 10: Expected a stage @ line 10, column 9.
           lock(resource: 'myResource') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 10: Stage does not have a name @ line 10, column 9.
           lock(resource: 'myResource') {
           ^

WorkflowScript: 10: Nothing to execute within stage "null" @ line 10, column 9.
           lock(resource: 'myResource') {
           ^

3 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:116)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:257)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Finished: FAILURE
```

What's the problem here?  The [documentation](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/10/16/stage-lock-milestone/#lock) explicitly states:

> `lock` can be also used to wrap multiple stages into a single
>   concurrency unit

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that, despite the fact that declarative pipelines were [technically available in beta in September, 2016](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/09/19/blueocean-beta-declarative-pipeline-pipeline-editor/), the blog post you reference (from October) is documenting scripted pipelines, not declarative (it doesn't say as much, so I feel your pain). Lockable resources hasn't been baked in as a declarative pipeline step in a way that would enable the feature you're looking for yet.

You can do:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('one') {
      steps {
        lock('something') {
          echo 'stage one'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But you can't do:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    lock('something') {
      stage('one') {
        steps {
          echo 'stage one'
        }
      }
      stage('two') {
        steps {
          echo 'stage two'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you can't do:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('one') {
      lock('something') {
        steps {
          echo 'stage one'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could use a scripted pipeline for this use case.

Comment: The issue is still open: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43336

Comment: Note that lock requires lockable-resources plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/lockable-resources

Comment: This approved answer is out-of-date.  The better answer for declarative pipelines in today's world is below

Comment: @JeffBennett Yep, you're right, this answer was correct and is no longer the best answer. The above jira issue was closed as resolved in 2019.

Comment: Do you know how this was resolved? I only found this PR [1] that was closed as duplicate to another PR which was never merged. I couldn't find the functionality yet.

@JeffBennett Is there an answer that allows locking of some, not all pipeline steps?

[1] https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin/pull/179

Answer (score 99):

It should be noted that you can lock *all* stages in a pipeline by using the lock option:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        lock resource: 'shared_resource_lock'
    }
    stages {
        stage('will_already_be_locked') {
            steps {
                echo "I am locked before I enter the stage!"
            }
        }
        stage('will_also_be_locked') {
            steps {
                echo "I am still locked!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I tried this but unfortunately it won't prevent additional pipeline builds from taking up an executor slot, which is what I need. I've since hooked up a local build agent with a single executor slot to exclusively care of pipeline builds.

Comment: I've spent a lot of time on searching how to block concurrent builds in multibranch pipeline. And this simple one line of code was this i was looking for.

Comment: This should be de approved answer!

Comment: Awesome answer, used this 3 years later and it did exactly what I needed it to.

Comment: Perfect, this should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: This is a great suggestion except environment variables are not accessible from `options` blocks.  Once again, Jenkins twists itself into inedible pretzels...

Answer (score 54):

This has since been addressed.

You can lock multiples stages by grouping them in a parent stage, like this :

```
stage('Parent') {
  options {
    lock('something')
  }
  stages {
    stage('one') {
      ...
    }
    stage('two') {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

(Don't forget you need the *Lockable Resources* Plugin)

Comment: Hi Samuel, I cannot make this work with declarative pipelines plugin version 2.5 (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin).
What version do you have? Or maybe you are using scripted pipelines?
Thanks!

Comment: @gusgonnet I made it work in a declarative pipeline, on Jenkins 2.121.2, pipeline 2.5 and lockable-resources 2.3

Comment: Worked like a charm! I have a Parallel stage that I needed the entire set to be locked

Comment: Notice that this example is not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/72491324/1866870 example which has a dynamic variable (env.BRANCH_NAME)

Answer (score 3):

Altho the `options{}` block offers this functionality it is not posible to use it in some use cases.

Lets say that you have to name your `lock()` with a specific name depending on a branch or an environment. You have a pipeline which you dont want to be block by `disableConcurrentBuilds()` and lock resources depending on a discriminator. You can not name your `lock()` inside the `options{}` block by using a environment variable or any other variable from the pipeline because the block is evaluated outside the agent.

The best solution in my opinion is the following:

```
pipeline {
 agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage('Wrapper') {
      steps {
        script {
          lock(env.BRANCH_NAME) {
             stage('Stage 1') {
               sh('echo "stage1"')
             }
             stage('Stage 2') {
               sh('echo "stage2"')
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the `script {}` block takes a block of Scripted Pipeline and executes that in the Declarative Pipeline so no `steps{}` are allowed inside.

Answer (score 2):

If the resource is only used by this pipeline you could also disable concurrent builds:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }
    stages {
        stage('will_already_be_locked') {
            steps {
                echo "I am locked before I enter the stage!"
            }
        }
        stage('will_also_be_locked') {
            steps {
                echo "I am still locked!"
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't block builds coming for different branches

Answer (score 1):

I run multiple build and test containers on the same build nodes. The test containers must lock up the node name as db username for the tests.

```
lock(resource: "${env.NODE_NAME}" as String, variable: 'DBUSER')
```

Locks in options are computed at load time, but NODE_NAME is unknown that early. In order to lock multiple stages for visual effect, we can create stages inside script block, i.e. 'run test' stage in the snippet. The stage visualization is just as good as other stage blocks.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('refresh') {
            steps {
                echo "freshing on $NODE_NAME"
                lock(resource: "${env.NODE_NAME}" as String, variable: 'DBUSER') {
                    sh '''
                        printenv | sort
                    '''
                    script {
                        stage('run test')
                        sh '''
                            printenv | sort
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```