# Jenkins pipeline lock is not getting released

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting this null pointer exception and the lock is not getting freed, it was working correctly for a long and suddenly started to throw this exceptions

any one has any idea?

```
stage('Deploy to iDev') {       
    steps {
        script {
            lock(resource: "$DEV_LOCK", inversePrecedence: true) {
                milestone (15)
                ansiColor('xterm') {
                    ansibleTower credential: '',
                    extraVars: "$DEV_ANSIBLE_PARAMS",
                    importTowerLogs: true,
                        importWorkflowChildLogs: false,
                        inventory: '',
                        jobTags: '',
                        jobTemplate: "$DEV_ANSIBLE_ID",
                        jobType: 'run',
                        limit: '',
                        removeColor: false,
                        skipJobTags: '',
                        templateType: 'job',
                        towerServer: "$TOWER_SERVER",
                        verbose: true
                }
            }

            if ("$DEV_CONTAINER_JOB" != 'NA') {
                build job: "$DEV_CONTAINER_JOB"
            }
            if ("$DEV_TEST_JOB" != 'NA') {
                build job: DEV_TEST_JOB, parameters: [[$class: DEV_TEST_PARAMS_CLASS, name: DEV_TEST_PARAMS_NAME, value:  DEV_TEST_PARAMS_VALUE]]
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            // We want to email the development team.           
        }
        aborted {
            echo "aborted.. during deploy to iDev"
        }
    }
}
```

errors are below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.freeResources(LockableResourcesManager.java:323)
    at org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.unlockNames(LockableResourcesManager.java:367)
    at org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockStepExecution$Callback.finished(LockStepExecution.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.BodyExecutionCallback$TailCall.onSuccess(BodyExecutionCallback.java:114)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$SuccessAdapter.receive(CpsBodyExecution.java:368)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Outcome.resumeFrom(Outcome.java:73)
```

Comment: can you share your pipeline with us?

Comment: updated the ticket..

Answer (score 2):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098993/how-to-lock-multiple-stages-of-declarative-jenkins-pipeline)

you need to do this as the lock is a declarative step or wrapper

```
stage('Deploy to iDev') {
    steps {
        lock(resource: "$DEV_LOCK", inversePrecedence: true) {
            script {
               .
                .
                .
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might run into problems with `$DEV_LOCK` too, depending how you defined it. You might be able to do `"${env.DEV_LOCK}"` or `"${DEV_LOCK}"`

---

Looking a bit closer, I think you only need to `script` the `if` statements. You could even put `build job...` into separate stages using [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) clauses with expressions and lose the `script` altogether and lock the whole pipeline as per my first link answer

Comment: I tried your suggestion and my pipeline still failed with null pointer exceptions. I have put the lock outside  the script.

I believe its a Jenkins bug

Comment: anyone know how to deal with this case ?

Comment: I looked at the code for the plugin. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: I am using Jenkins ver. 2.157

Comment: what is the plugin version for the lock plugin?

Answer (score 0):

As a first look, I would say that `$DEV_LOCK` doesn't exist at the moment it is evaluated. Just for the sake of argument, you can try to change it for a static string temporary, let's say

```
lock(resource: "foo", inversePrecedence: true)
```

Getting a bit deeper into it, and

- seeing this line of the error stack trace
  `org.jenkins.plugins.lockableresources.LockableResourcesManager.freeResources(LockableResourcesManager.java:323)`
- judging by the date of this post,
- and the commit history of the plugin...

...I would say that we are talking about this line in the plugin's code: https://github.com/jenkinsci/lockable-resources-plugin/blob/79034dcd1c12f88030b0990356ad9f7c63d1937e/src/main/java/org/jenkins/plugins/lockableresources/LockableResourcesManager.java#L323

The line is

```
323. private synchronized void freeResources(List<String> unlockResourceNames, @Nullable Run<?, ?> build) {
321.  for (String unlockResourceName : unlockResourceNames) {
322.            for (LockableResource resource : this.resources) {
323.                if (resource != null && resource.getName() != null && resource.getName().equals(unlockResourceName)) {
```

we can see that `resource` is not null, and `resource.getName()` is not null, so the only possible null thing there is `unlockResourceName`, which makes sense since it is not checked in the lines above.

So it looks like the resource name of your resource (remember that your resource was `$DEV_LOCK`) happens to be null.

so I would say that the test proposed above, using just `lock(resource: "foo", inversePrecedence: true)` to see if the problems come from there, would be a good starting point. If it works, then you can decide if you really need `$DEV_LOCK` as a env variable, or you can change it for something static. If you needed it then take it from there trying to find out where it is unset, or if it is actually set somewhere.