# Is there a way to "debounce" Jenkins builds in a Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, multibranch-pipeline

I understand there are ways to [disallow concurrent builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492688/how-to-limit-jenkins-concurrent-multibranch-pipeline-builds) and maybe even to [throttle builds with a plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/) or with a quiet period. But what I really want is to be able to debounce multibranch builds. It's not uncommon in our workflow for many branches to be merged in quick succession, causing many builds to queue up for the target branch. I'd like to add a debounce wait period, so only the most recent build is run.